# Dynamic LINQ: Comparing Nested Data With Parent Property

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, expression, dynamic-linq

I've a class with following structure:

```
 public class BestWayContext
{
    public Preference Preference { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceRate> ServiceRate { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceRate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Carrier { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
}
```

and I've dynamic linq expression string

**"Preference != null && ServiceRate.Any(Carrier == Preference.Carrier)"**

and I want to convert above string in Dynamic LINQ as follows:

```
  var expression = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<BestWayContext, bool>(condition, null).Compile();
```

But it showing following error:

[image]

Please correct me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wanted to do something like this:

```
var bwc = new BestWayContext
{
    Preference = new Preference { Carrier = "test" },
    DueDate = DateTime.Now,
    ServiceRate = new List<ServiceRate>
    {
        new ServiceRate
        {
            Carrier = "test",
            DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now,
            Id = 2,
            Rate = 100,
            Service = "testService"
        }
    }
};

string condition = "Preference != null && ServiceRate.Any(Carrier == @0)";
var expression = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<BestWayContext, bool>(condition, bwc.Preference.Carrier).Compile();
bool res = expression(bwc); // true
bwc.ServiceRate.First().Carrier = "test1"; // just for testing this -> there is only one so I've used first
res = expression(bwc); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helps me a lott but, we can not change condition string as you changed "ServiceRate.Any(Carrier == @0)". So is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I dont know a way to do that(there may be one). It looks like the condition inside the Any has a narrow scope. If I'll come up with something, I'll update here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Preference which belong to BestWayContext but you didn't tell the compiler about that. If i write your expression on Linq i will do as follows:

[List of BestWayContext].Where(f => f.Preference != null && f.ServiceRate.Where(g => g.Carrier == f.Preference.Carrier)
);

As you see i specified to use Preference of BestWayContext.